# What does "missing topic" error mean in APNS?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have implemented **APNS** in my code, 
I am trying to test my app on **ad-hoc distribution profile**.
Device is getting registered properly.
But i am not getting any push notification on my device.
And feedback shows **130** as response which means `"missing topic."`
What does **topic** referes to? What is **topic** in my **push notification**?

Comment: ad-hoc provisioning or ad-hoc distribution? seems like the first one should work with development certificate & sandbox apns server and the latter with production certificate and 'real' apns server... just guessing though.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for noticing that.... i have edited my question. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be covered in the [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) on the subject:

> The topic is currently the bundle identifier of the target application
>   on an iOS device.

Comment: that we need to set in entitlement.plist or where? cos everything was working fine on development profile. Or it's error while creating ck.pem for distribution profile?

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @therealprashant I have fixed the link with the equivalent link in the new documentation format. "In general, the topic is your app’s bundle ID, but it may have a suffix based on the push notification’s type."

Comment: That text is now:
_The topic for the notification. In general, the topic is your app’s bundle ID/app ID._
So I suppose Bundle ID still works.

Answer (score 2):

it solve，

now need to config topic, see request, for example:
APNS MissingTopic is because you use first request, you should use second request, add a topic. it's OK

***topic is your app's bundleID***

1. single topic's request:

   ```
   HEADERS
   - END_STREAM
   + END_HEADERS
     :method = POST
     :scheme = https
     :path = /3/device/00fc13adff785122b4ad28809a3420982341241421348097878e577c991de8f0
     host = api.development.push.apple.com  
     apns-id = eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b
     apns-expiration = 0
     apns-priority = 10
   DATA
   + END_STREAM
     { "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
   ```
2. multiple topic's request

   ```
   HEADERS
   - END_STREAM
   + END_HEADERS
     :method = POST
     :scheme = https
     :path = /3/device/00fc13adff785122b4ad28809a3420982341241421348097878e577c991de8f0
     host = api.development.push.apple.com
     apns-id = eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b
     apns-expiration = 0
     apns-priority = 10
     apns-topic = <MyAppTopic> 
   DATA
   + END_STREAM
     { "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
   ```

Comment: What they meant by `- END_STREAM` , `+ END_STREAM ` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

New error table
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

400: MissingTopic:
The apns-topic header of the request was not specified and was required. The apns-topic header is mandatory when the client is connected using a certificate that supports multiple topics.